# Error using repeat loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function using repeat but I am receiving the below error. Why am I getting following error?

- After few suggestion, my error was resolved but I am still not able to get the desired dataframe as output. Much appreciated for you time and feedback.!

  l<-5
  m<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,6,7,8), b=c(7,8,9,6,7,4))
  b<-data.frame(x=c(7,3,9,2,3,4),y=c(6,7,18,5,6,8))
  for(i in 1:l){

  for(j in 1:l){

  ```
  if(m[j,2]==b[j,1])
  ```

  { break}

  m[j,2]<-b[j,2]

  }
  }

Error:

> `Error in if (m[j, 2] == b[j, 1]) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

a   b
1   6
2   8
3   18
6   6
7   7
8   8

Above is my desired dataframe m, where values of column b are populated after the comparison with another dataframe.

I want m[,2] to compare with b[,1] and if there is a match, then m[,2]<-b[,2]

Comment: Where is the `repeat` statement?

Comment: Why loop `l` to 5 when `m` only has 3 rows? (Same for `b`.) (Hint, this might be the cause of the error.)

Comment: sorry @akrun...I mean repeat loop in R.

Comment: What should your result look like?

Comment: thanks for your feedback guys, I have just made some changes in the code. Hope that will make it easier for others to know my doubt. Sorry for the not being clear enough.

Comment: @r2evans....yes you are right, that was the cause of error, I have also updated the question to better reflect my query. Cheers for looking at my query mate!

Comment: @VaibhavThapliyal can you update the question as it is not clear if it was resolved by updates. Now there is no error.

Comment: @Bulat thanks for writing. After one of the above suggestions my error was resolved but I am still unable to get the data frame with desired values. Thanks again for writing.!

Comment: You need to update the question, it is not clear what you are after. e.g. remove error message.

Answer (score 0):

Number of rows in both the data frames are less than 5, so assign

```
l<-3
```

it works now

Comment: thanks for your help, I have made slight change to the question. Your response is right though, l<-5 was the cause of error.